# On what stage netem introduce the delay

Tags: linux, networking, emulation

I have a client to access a web service on a server which resides in another machine. I want to control the request so that it's sent to the server normally without any interference however once the response is back, i want to hold the response for some delay before my client consumes the response.

Can i achieve this goal using netem? If not, are there any other tools to do that?

Thanks,

Balin

Comment: netem holds the packet, and deliver it after the delay. No concepts of layer.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi i probably know what netem does, it can't control the delay of the response since it just receives it from the physical layer and ends. i need another tool to do what i want in the layers above TCP/IP